# Postfix Ignores PHP mail() function

Tags: php, apache, sendmail, phpmailer, postfix-mta

I'm successfully sending mail using PHP using the mail() function but the sending is showing up as the server address and not what I have configured in the script. Postfix is installed on the apache server.  On [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/258035/why-postfix-doesnt-follow-from-header-from-php-mail) I read to use the -f and -r flags but that does not work either like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,'From: ' . $fromname . ' <'.$from.'>', "-f $from -r mybounceemail@example.com");
```

The best I've been able to do is change the Postfix myorigin which is the local machine name hostname to the parent domain of the machine name.

This leads me to believe Postfix is ignoring or stripping the From: element?

Comment: link the ubuntu page

Comment: How do I do that? @KarolyHorvath

Comment: Nevermind, I realize what you are saying now...It was a serverfault answer...I added the link.

Comment: Are you using any WebPanel? If not, did you try editing the etc/postfix/main.conf file?

Comment: Hmm, mail expects 5 parameters max, albeit 6 given. How did you get it working? Error messages, logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could let the Postfix do its job rewriting headers and adding proper `From:` addresses. For this, Postfix has `sender_canonical_maps`.

Let's say your web server (or a process manager) runs under user named `username`, and you want to have `support@example.com` in the `From:` header of your emails instead of unclear `username@servername.example.com`. Then, canonical map would contain:

```
#/etc/postfix/canonical
username support@example.com
```

Configuring Postfix to use it can't be easier:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/canonical
postconf -e sender_canonical_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
```

Other option is to tell postfix to mark all emails send from you server as send from `support@example.com` by means of `luser_relay`:

```
postconf -ev luser_relay=support@example.com
```

If you can't do it, quite possible someone already did this for you, but did that wrong. That could be a reason why you can't change `From:` address since it is being forcedly overwritten by Postfix.

Answer (score 10):

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,'From: ' . $fromname . ' <'.$from.'>', "-f $from -r mybounceemail@example.com");
```

Cannot work as [mail()](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php) only accepts 5 parameters: `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`

For me both

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, null, "-r sender@example.com");
mail($to, $subject, $message, 'Name <something@example.com>', "-r sender@example.com");
```

work (I don't have any additional restrictions in postfix which might rewrite senders). Also make sure that the sender is properly formatted (no spaces or whatsoever).

However, I recommend to adjust the `sendmail_path` setting in your php.ini to include the "-r mybounceemail@example.com" parameter.

If it doesn't work for you, you should post the mail headers here and check your log files for warnigns/errors.

PS: Please make sure you don't pass user entered data directly to `mail()`, because if users can insert newlines (such as `\nCC: something@example.com` in subject, to mail or from mail) your server might be used for spamming.

Answer (score 5):

You've got the header argument in your [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) call twice and thus, your `$additional_parameters` argument isn't being used because it's the 6th argument in a function that only accepts 5. You should instead move the header to be included with the rest of your headers:

```
//Be mindful to protect from email injection attacks.
$fromname = str_replace("\n", "", $fromname);
$from = str_replace("\n", "", $from);

//This assumes that $headers is already set, containing your other headers
$headers .= 'From: ' . $fromname . ' <'.$from.">\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f $from -r mybounceemail@example.com");
```

Using this, I would expect that your 5th argument is now redundant and could be simplified to:

```
$fromname = str_replace("\n", "", $fromname);
$from = str_replace("\n", "", $from);

$headers .= 'From: ' . $fromname . ' <'.$from.">\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: `trim` does not help against newlines within the string.

Comment: There is no need to specify `-r` and `-f` at the same time.

Comment: @MrTux - you are correct, those flags appear to do exactly the same thing.  However, I'm not convinced it's causing the problems described in the question; for clarity purposes I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, the syntax for `mail` function is as follows:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $parameters);
```

So in your case, if you want to specify a different "From" address and a different "Return path" your code should be as follows:

```
$to = "john@example.com";
$subject = "Your reset email";
$message = "<message text / html>";
$from = "support@example.com";
$bounceEmail = "bouncey@example.com";
$headers = array(
    "From: " . $from
);
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
$parameters = "-r" . $bounceEmail;

// Send it!
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $parameters);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Quoting PHP's documentation:

String to be inserted at the end of the email header.

This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). **Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n)**. If outside data are used to compose this header, the data should be sanitized so that no unwanted headers could be injected.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: ^ (MrTux's comment got deleted but I'll leave this here for prosperity)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cron was using the wrong instance of php.

So you can specify the php instance by doing something like:

```
33 * * * * /usr/bin/php /location/of/file/filename.php >> /var/log/syslog
```